# Windows 10 - How to disable Windows File Protection?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization, resources, wfp

I'm trying to modify my Windows Laptop to use my own custom icons. I found a software called "Resource Hacker" that can go into a file, and in my case, an executable, and change any data within it, like an icon.  I'm currently trying to edit `explorer.exe` (`C:\Windows\explorer.exe`).  When I try to save my changes to the file, it gives the error message "Cannot rename original file. Saving cancelled." I did some research, and apparently its because of Windows File Protection (WFP).

I tried:

1. Running resource hacker as administrator
2. I tried following the instructions here: https://www.askvg.com/how-to-fix-cannot-create-file-error-message-problem-while-saving-files-in-resource-hacker/
3. Creating the `SFCDisable` DWORD in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon` and restarting my laptop

Comment: You have to give the SFCDisable a value, what value did you give it?.....https://www.technipages.com/enable-disable-wfp

Comment: **I said in windows 10.** i set it to 1

Comment: Try value ffffff9d

Comment: actually now i just got a totally new computer bc the old one broke and i downgraded it to Windows 1809 so i could use CustomizerGod and it worked